# Microcontroller - Measure Resistance in Circuit

Tags: arduino, analog, resistance, coil

I am creating circuit that will control power of heater coil.

For controling power I am using Arduino PWM that controls voltage and by Ohm's Law I am calculating desired power.

**P = V^2 / R**

Now the problem is next:

Heater coil is low resistance (0.3R - 2R), and resistance can vary with coil replacing. Because impedance of coil is used to calculate power I want to read coil resistance with microcontroller.

I am using this circuit:

[image]

Battery voltage is 3.2 - 4.2V.

Power from battery directly goes to the heater coil and it is controlled by MOSFET. After that there is DC-DC StepUP that provides enough voltage for Microcontroller and MOSFET.

VBAT is read by Microcontroller, so Microcontroller have info about current battery voltage that will go through LOAD (Heater Coil).

Now my question is how to measure LOAD (R5) Ressistance with microcontroller?

Comment: Note that the "heater coil" may well be a PTC, changing its resistance as it gets warm/hot.

Comment: Do you really need to control *power*? Could you revert to controlling *temperature* (PID?)? Or current?

Comment: I need to know resistance while coil is not running.

Comment: Miljan, the heating coil's resistance value is a function of its temperature, and the value is likely to be nonlinear with increasing temperature.  In other words, measuring the coil's cold temperature resistance isn't particularly useful for you.  This YouTube video discusses the nonlinear current-voltage relationship for an incandescent light bulb; however, this principle also applies to your heating element.  https://youtu.be/ZiaNgaixkYE

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, adding a current sense resistor would be easiest.

You can put it anywhere in series with the load, as long as it is thermally isolated from the load. I'd put it on the MOSFET source to make the voltage measurement single-ended and therefore a little easier.

Then use an instrumentation amplifier with a low pass filter to measure the average voltage across that sense resistor. That measurement will give you the current through the load, and since you already know the voltage, you have everything you need.

I see from your other comments that you might be concerned about making an online measurement (ie. when the heater is running). I'd suggest this concern is not warranted - it's going to be a far more accurate measurement if you take it during operation. Taking an offline measurement (ie. without turning the coil on) might not tell you much because the resistance of the coil will change during operation.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using two extra components, Q5 and Rm:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5MpG0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the heater is off (HEAT is low, Q4 is off), switch on another path for current through the heater R5, this time via Q5 and a 10Ω sense resistor Rm, by bringing MEASURE high.

Heater R5 and Rm then form a potential divider between BAT and ground, with their junction being node M. By measuring the potential at M and BAT, you can determine the resistance of R5.

Assuming the MOSEFT Q5's on resistance is negligible, much lower than R5, the  voltage at M will be:

$$ V_M = V_{BAT} \times \frac{R_M}{R_M + R_5} $$

With \$V_{BAT}=4.2V\$, values for \$V_M\$ would be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_5 &= 0.3\Omega \rightarrow V_M = 4.08V \\ \\
R_5 &= 2.0\Omega \rightarrow V_M = 3.50V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Measure this with the microcontroller, which should implement the above relationship rearranged to find R5:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_5 &= R_{M} \left( \frac{V_{BAT}}{V_M} - 1 \right) \\ \\
&= 10 \left( \frac{V_{BAT}}{V_M} - 1 \right) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Most robust would be to measure the voltage across the resistor (differential measurement - perhaps an instrumentation amplifier or such) and the current through the resistor - giving you both unkowns in \$R=\frac{V}{I}\$. The current can be measured with a very small current shunt.

If you can do with low accuracy, it could be possible to calculate it by using your NMOS in saturation, where it will act as a constant current source. If you then measure the voltage across the resistor you can use the "set" current from the MOSFET and the measured voltage to have a guess at your power. Ofcourse, the error will likely be larger since you are relying on not-so-well-defined parameters of the MOSFET with respect to temperature and process drift.

Comment: Can you better explain me how to do differential measurement without starting heater coil? If I put GND between FET and coil it will start coil.

Comment: @MiljanIlić You cannot measure resistance without sending some current through the resistor to measure. But you probably don't have to because you probably don't need to know the resistance of the coil when it's not running. So the algorithm is simply to turn on the coil briefly (just enough to have inductive and capacitive effects stabilize somewhat), take your measurement and then turn the coil back off. Calculate your coefficients from the measured values and start the control algorithm.

Comment: @MiljanIlić Another, possibly more stable approach, would be to basically control power in a more direct "energy/time-unit" way: You turn on the coil and keep measuring the voltage and current through it. For each measurement you can compute the *energy* as `U * I * t` and check if you have already provided enough *energy* for the current control time interval (like, 0.1 second) and if so, turn off the coil; else let it run and measure on. This basically results in creating a software PWM at the control output.

Comment: @JimmyB I must know resistance before igniting coil, so I can calculate voltage that MOSFET will provide to get desired power.

Comment: I have measured battery voltage, I can measure voltage between  MOSFET and coil, but how I can limit negative battery voltage to be enough to measure resistance and not enough to turn coil on full power.

Comment: @MiljanIlić You use PWM to control the coil, don't you? That's nothing else than turning on the coil full power for (more or less) brief periods anyway...

Comment: Yes, I use PWM to control coil, but if I supply GND between MOSFET and Coil to measure resistance by using differential measurement, coil will ignite and start heating.